# Melting data frame to produce scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2, melt

I have the following data structure.

```
library(MASS)

mu1 <- c(2, -3)
mu2 <- c(2, 5)
rho <- 0.5
s1 <- 1
s2 <- 3
Sigma <- matrix(c(s1^2, rho * s1 * s2, rho * s1 * s2, s2^2), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 2)
n <- 50

X1 <- mvrnorm(n, mu = mu1, Sigma = Sigma)
X2 <- mvrnorm(n, mu = mu2, Sigma = Sigma)
y <- rep(c(0, 1), each = n)
X <- data.frame(rbind(X1, X2), class = y)
```

I wonder how to properly melt (produce long form) this data frame to produce the following scatter plot.

[image]

Comment: this is just `ggplot(X, aes(X1, X2, colour = factor(class))) + geom_point()` is it not?

Comment: @rawr Yes it is, but I wonder if there is a solution with melting the data frame.

Comment: The data are currently in the right format for this plot. What do you think is wrong about it?

Comment: @Heroka, it's OK than. I wasn't sure.

Comment: Generally, if ggplot does what you want without a lot of code-repeating (like 5 calls to `geom_line`), you're doing fine.